# Mix Vue Router with classic Symfony app routing

Tags: javascript, symfony, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm working on the transition of a classic Symfony application using Twig, into a full VueJS App.

VueJS is already working on some pages using symfony routing.

I now need to use the Vue Router to navigate between multiple components.

I followed the Vue Router doc and it's working perfectly but when I click on my router link, the content of component template linked to the route is displayed but the non vue page content stay because it's not generated by Vue inside the `<router-view></router-view>`

So I'm trying to mix my old Symfony routing with the vue router and alternate between VueJS content and non VueJS content.

I though to add a condition to check if `router-view` is empty and then show classic content if not show the other one.

Actually my `router-view` is inside a Twig template so I can't acces to all vue props.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <router-link to="/foo">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

I don't find any way to add a condition, according to VueRouter doc I did'nt find something to do it, is this simply doable ?

If I need to find another way, maybe create a component who will switch between `router-view` and `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` but I think twig will not understand my block because the Twig rendering will be before Vue add content to the page.

Did someone already had this problematic and succeed to fix it ?